# Python - tweepy doesn't return response object when using create_tweet

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm dealing with rate limits on the Twitter API. Right now i'm rate limited and i'm trying to understand for how long i will be by accessing the `rate-limit-remaining` header. The problem with my code is that tweepy instead of returning the response, raises an error which makes iresponse =

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token,
                access_token=token,
                access_token_secret=token_secret,
                consumer_key=consumer_key,
                consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
                return_type=requests.Response)

response = client.create_tweet(text=message)
print('RESPONSE', response)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can set `wait_on_rate_limit` argument of `tweepy.Client` class to `True` to [create an instance that will automatically wait for the appropriate amount of time(using `time.sleep`) when the rate limit reached](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/bb0f581f24d7d1909f40c0bf8c6be7c0c15940ba/examples/API_v1/rate_limit_handling.py#L13-L16).

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't tell me how much i need to wayt. Basically it says "Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 901 seconds.", and after 900 seconds it will simply reset and give me the same message

Comment: But from the [source code of tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/bb0f581f24d7d1909f40c0bf8c6be7c0c15940ba/tweepy/client.py#L103-L113) it properly handle this case based on the `x-rate-limit-reset` header.

Comment: This is weird then, because every time i wait for X seconds the clock will simply reset and i still can't tweet. Maybe there is some other limit? Like maximum 50 tweets per day

Comment: Ok, If you want to inspect the error you can catch it using  `except tweepy.errors.HTTPException as e` and then you can use `e.response` to inspect the response object.